# Does Gensim handle multi-word terms when processing Wikipedia corpus?

Tags: nlp, lda, gensim, topic-modeling, lsa

I was reading the [Experiments on the English Wikipedia](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation) tutorial and noticed that many of the topics generated by LSA and LDA contained multi-word terms that had clearly been concatenated e.g. *northamerica*, *hockeyarchives*

Could someone indicate where this takes place. I have looked at *gensim.scripts.make_wiki*, *gensim.corpora.wikicorpus* and *genesis.utils*.